# Issues returning values from SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an application that is supposed to take a decimal input, push into a stored procedure and return a char value for use in the application.

For some reason, all of my other stored procedures seem to be working fine, however this one particular stored procedure is not working at all.

Originally, the input was in the form of a dropdown list, however the values in the list were incorrect.

For example: 0.975 in the SQL Server table would show up as 1.000 in the drop down list. 1.025 somehow became 1.050. 1.075 became 2.000

So I tossed out the drop down list in favor of a text box. I still am not receiving proper return values. Actually, I am not getting any values back at all.

Here is my code:

Form:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Select RZD: "></asp:Label>   
<asp:TextBox ID="rzdTB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="rzdFSLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Code behind:

```
fileNameGenerator fNG = new fileNameGenerator();
fNG.rzd = Convert.ToDouble(rzdTB.Text);
fNG.fileGenerator();
rzdFSLabel.Text = fNG.rzdfsOUT;

Label13.Text = fNG.bcfsOUT + fNG.rzdfsOUT + fNG.anglefsOUT + fNG.powerfsOUT;
lBO.fileName = fNG.bcfsOUT + fNG.rzdfsOUT + fNG.anglefsOUT + fNG.powerfsOUT;

fileNameGenerator()

//declare rzd variable - convert to double
//declare rzdSymbol as the output
c2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rzd", SqlDbType.Float).Value =rzd;
SqlParameter rzdSymbol = new SqlParameter("@rzdSymbol", SqlDbType.VarChar);
rzdSymbol.Size = 2;
rzdSymbol.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
c2.Parameters.Add(rzdSymbol);

//open the connection string and execute the stored procedures
conn.Open();
c1.ExecuteNonQuery();
c2.ExecuteNonQuery();
c3.ExecuteNonQuery();
c4.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

bcfsOUT = c1.Parameters["@bcFS"].Value.ToString();

//string sdfsOUT to label2
rzdfsOUT = c2.Parameters["@rzdSymbol"].Value.ToString();
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.getRZDSymbol
(
    @rzd decimal(10,5),
    @rzdSymbol varchar(2) OUTPUT
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT @rzdSymbol = rzdSymbol
    FROM fileSymbolTable
    WHERE rzd = @rzd
```

Comment: Can you post the table schema for fileSymbolTable? As T.S. alludes to, there may be a data type issue between @rzd, rzdSymbol and rzd.

Comment: @T.S. I originally had everything set as decimals. I have changed my code back to decimal. I still get no return value.

I changed to float because googling around, I found a suggestion from someone else's issues to try and change to float. Didn't work for me lol.

Comment: @BrentD There are 9 columns in the table, one of which is a time stamp. Here is the schema, I am detailing four columns for comparison. The baseCurve schema and code is exactly the same as the rzd parameter:
baseCurve - decimal(5,3)
baseCurveSymbol - varchar(5)
rzd - decimal(5,3)
rzdSymbol - varchar(5)

the two symbol columns should return varchars of two characters EX: KA, IJ, CE, etc...

Comment: @T.S. thank you so much for your responses, honestly I am pulling out my hair. I do get a value from that query. I assume that for <valid value> I am to use a filter @rzd? In which case, I am getting the expected varchar.

Comment: @T.S. Also, to answer your second question, the rzdSymbol is a varchar(5). I expect a two character value in return. Something like:

KA, IJ, CH, etc...

Once again, many thanks.

Comment: Also, sometimes in cases like this we have to ask, "Are you connecting to right DB?" Means, sometimes people run Sql query against one DB and code against another

Comment: @T.S. - I have adjusted the code, sad to say...no dice. The rest of the queries are fine, still no value.

Comment: @T.S.
Mate, I am ashamed to say, the problem was rather simple and I want to thank you for all of your help.

I did not realize I was pulling data from a db from the network development server and not my local machine. I dropped the table, imported the table from the db on my local machine and voila!

Seriously, thank you and to Brent.

Comment: I told you exactly that!

Comment: @T.S. LOL, it only took me a day to understand...next time feel free to pound the advice in my noggin.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I feel foolish, but the answer was rather simple.

I had a deep look at the c2 parameter while debugging. I kept seeing "FLOAT" as the rzd datatype. That seemed rather odd so I began investigating where exactly I was pulling data from. TO make matters more confusing, I have two databases on my local machine and one on a development server on our network. I believed I was still hooked into the local machine, but it turns I was pulling from the networked db.

Drop the table on the network, re-imported from the local machine and BAM!

All of a sudden it works. Imagine that...

Very sorry, but thank you all for the help.